# How do I test for empty elements in different places in an array? I.e. how can I test for whether a location has been dimensioned in a jagged array?

Tags: vba

I have an array Cdo in the form (j,0)(i,0). There are two exceptions: the addresses (j,0) or (j,0)(0), usually empty, may contain a string with an error message [never both at the same time].

Want to pass through those errors without generating a subscript out of range while also documenting it to the cleaned up array, Breaks (in two dimensions, (j,i)).

```
For j = 0 to Symbol
    If TypeName(Cdo(j,0)) <> "String" Then
        If TypeName(Cdo(j,0)(0)) <> "String" Then
            For i = 0 to UBound(Cdo(j,0))
                Breaks(j,i) = Cdo(j,0)(i,0)
            Next i
        End if
        Breaks(j,1) = "#N/A"
    End if
    Breaks(j,1) = "#TrancheDef"
Next j
```

I tried IsEmpty and looking for a string (shown), but they both throw errors when looking somewhere not dimensioned. I can't change the array as it comes in - how can I test whether a location, e.g. (403)(0)(0) "exists" so to speak?

Alternatively:
I could just check if Cdo(j,0)(i,0) exists - if not, then it should be one of the other two cases. Still revolves around the same fundamental question.

Comment: I am curious, isn't there any way to do something like Cdo.size()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function ItExists(byval j as integer) as boolean

  On Error Resume Next
  if lenb((j,0)(0)) then
  'Nothing
  end if
  ItExists=(err.number=0)
  On Error Goto 0

end function
```

Something like the above should work. Play with it to make it do what you want.

Comment: Thanks! I wish there was a way to test via a Boolean at the element level, though - On Error Resume Nexts scare me.

Comment: Not to worry, the big boys use it all the time, it's nice not to use it but you gotta do what you gotta do sometimes!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check if a array is initialized or not you have to use a dll function:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function SafeArrayGetDim Lib "oleaut32.dll" (ByRef saArray() As Any) As Long

Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim Cdo() As String
  'Cdo = Split("a,b,c", ",")

  If SafeArrayGetDim(Cdo) <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Array has been Initialized"
  End If

End Sub
```

maybe you can also use:

```
Private Declare Function VarPtrArray Lib "msvbvm60.dll" Alias "VarPtr" (Ptr() As Any) As Long
```

Regards Thomas

Comment: The array is definitely initialised - it's a jagged array with two 2-dimensional arrays. Problem is (403,0)(0) may exist while (403,0)(0,0) doesn't. Or (404,0)(0,0) exist while its parent (404,0)(0) doesn't. 

More precisely, instead of exist/doesn't exist, a subscript out of range error.

Comment: sorry... I'm confused... how do you create the array? in VBA there are normaly no "multi" Arrays like XX(a,b)(c,d) arrays - only XX(a,b,c,d, ...) ?! But if you got a error then it means the position you access is not validate => not initialized because you have the array XX(a,b) with contains the array(c,d) that is not initialized.

Comment: You can have a jagged array, i.e. an array within an array with heterogenous lengths in the child array. Referencing them looks like I showed above, e.g. (1,2)(2,2) is row 1 column 2 in the first array and row 2 column 2 in the array in row 1 column 2 of the first array. The array I'm referencing has 5,3, and 1 dimensions with the middle one being jagged. Why Nanex decides on this sadistic structure when there are only two REAL variables is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

I find another solution for the question

```
    Option Base 0
    Option Compare Binary
    Option Explicit

    Private Const VT_BYREF = &H4000
    Private Const VARIANT_DATA_OFFSET As Long = 8

    Private Declare Function SafeArrayGetDim Lib "oleaut32.dll" _
        (ByVal pSA As Long) _
        As Long

    Private Declare Function SafeArrayGetLBound Lib "oleaut32.dll" _
        (ByVal pSA As Long, _
         ByVal nDim As Long, _
         ByRef plLbound As Long) _
        As Long

    Private Declare Function SafeArrayGetUBound Lib "oleaut32.dll" _
        (ByVal pSA As Long, _
         ByVal nDim As Long, _
         ByRef plUbound As Long) _
        As Long

    Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" _
        (ByRef lpDest As Any, _
         ByRef lpSource As Any, _
         ByVal lByteLen As Long)
    '


    Public Function LBoundEx(ByRef vArray As Variant, _
                             Optional ByVal lDimension As Long = 1) As Long

        Dim iDataType As Integer
        Dim pSA As Long

        'Make sure an array was passed in:
        If IsArray(vArray) Then

            'Try to get the pointer:
            CopyMemory pSA, ByVal VarPtr(vArray) + VARIANT_DATA_OFFSET, 4

            If pSA Then

                'If byref then deref the pointer to get the actual pointer:
                CopyMemory iDataType, vArray, 2
                If iDataType And VT_BYREF Then
                    CopyMemory pSA, ByVal pSA, 4
                End If

                If pSA Then
                    If lDimension > 0 Then
                        'Make sure this is a valid array dimension:
                        If lDimension <= SafeArrayGetDim(pSA) Then
                            'Get the LBound:
                            SafeArrayGetLBound pSA, lDimension, LBoundEx
                        Else
                            LBoundEx = -1
                        End If
                    Else
                        Err.Raise vbObjectError Or 10000, "LBoundEx", "Invalid Dimension"
                    End If
                Else
                    LBoundEx = -1
                End If
            Else
                LBoundEx = -1
            End If
        Else
            Err.Raise vbObjectError Or 10000, "LBoundEx", "Not an array"
        End If

    End Function


    Public Function UBoundEx(ByRef vArray As Variant, _
                             Optional ByVal lDimension As Long = 1) As Long

        Dim iDataType As Integer
        Dim pSA As Long

        'Make sure an array was passed in:
        If IsArray(vArray) Then

            'Try to get the pointer:
            CopyMemory pSA, ByVal VarPtr(vArray) + VARIANT_DATA_OFFSET, 4

            If pSA Then

                'If byref then deref the pointer to get the actual pointer:
                CopyMemory iDataType, vArray, 2
                If iDataType And VT_BYREF Then
                    CopyMemory pSA, ByVal pSA, 4
                End If

                If pSA Then
                    If lDimension > 0 Then
                        'Make sure this is a valid array dimension:
                        If lDimension <= SafeArrayGetDim(pSA) Then
                            'Get the UBound:
                            SafeArrayGetUBound pSA, lDimension, UBoundEx
                        Else
                            UBoundEx = -1
                        End If
                    Else
                        Err.Raise vbObjectError Or 10000, "UBoundEx", "Invalid Dimension"
                    End If
                Else
                    UBoundEx = -1
                End If
            Else
                UBoundEx = -1
            End If
        Else
            Err.Raise vbObjectError Or 10000, "UBoundEx", "Not an array"
        End If

    End Function



    Private Function test()
    Dim Cdo() As Variant
    Dim a() As String
    Dim b() As String

    ReDim Cdo(1 To 5, 1 To 2)
    ReDim a(1 To 2)
    ReDim b(1 To 3, 1 To 2)

    Cdo(1, 2) = a
    Cdo(2, 2) = b

    '- test
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim z As Long
    Dim q As Long
    Dim ok As Boolean

    x = 2
    y = 2
    z = 2
    q = 2 '- set to -1 for Cdo(x, y)(z) and to >=0 for Cdo(x, y)(z,q)

    ok = False

    If (UBoundEx(Cdo, 1) >= x) Then
      If (UBoundEx(Cdo, 2) >= y) Then
        If (Not IsEmpty(Cdo(x, y))) Then
          If (UBoundEx(Cdo(x, y), 1) >= z) Then
            If (q >= 0) Then
              If (UBoundEx(Cdo(x, y), 2) >= q) Then
                Debug.Print Cdo(x, y)(z, q)
                ok = True
              End If
            Else
              If (UBoundEx(Cdo(x, y), 2) = -1) Then
                Debug.Print Cdo(x, y)(z)
                ok = True
              End If
            End If
          End If
        End If
      End If
    End If

    if (ok) then
      debug.print "OK"
    end it
  End Function
```